# JQuery / XML Finding and returning 1 row

Tags: xml, jquery

I've run into a bit of struggle with .find() and .attr() (I think) when trying to iterate through an XML and find and return children where the parent's .attr(value) is equal to what is being passed in the function.

What I have to do, and what is not seen here, is that I have approx 70 checkboxes, the IDs of those checkboxes are = to the value of OAData of this piece of XML

```
<OAData value='1'>
        <OAid>OA1</OAid>

    <BAC_Level_1>some text</BAC_Level_1>

    <Basel_Level_1>some text</Basel_Level_1>

    <Basel_Level_2>some text</Basel_Level_2>

    <Risk_Category_Level_3>some text</Risk_Category_Level_3>
 </OAData>
```

Desired Outcome: The desired outcome is that the user clicks on a button to submit which runs the function createrow() and when they do it will check to see if the checkbox is checked and if it is it will only iterate through those items in the XML where the OAData value is equal to the value of the boxes that are checked.

Where I think the problem is:

```
$(xml_list).find('OAData').each(function() {
```

I don't think I can replace it with:

```
$(xml_list).find('OAData').each.attr('value')(function() {
```

I only want to find OAData if the OAData value property is equal to what is passed by the function.

I may be in some sort of cart before the horse situation here - I'm more than a little strung out.

Section of code in question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function buildrow(checkboxid) {
          if(checkboxid === 'OA1'){ //This is the wrong way to go about this - need help here
                 function xml_parser(wrapper) {
             //Construct and display preloader
                 $('<div id="preload_xml"></div>').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading data" /><h3>Loading Data...</h3>').prependTo($('body'));

                 //Hide Content (this is sloppy but easy to customize..)
                 $(wrapper).hide();

         //Get XML Data
                 $.ajax({
                      type: 'GET',
                      url: 'xml/OA.xml',
                      dataType: 'xml',
                      success: function(xml_list) {

          //Remove preloader HTML & show data
                  $('#preload_xml').remove();
                  $(wrapper).show();

          var xmlArr = [];
          $(xml_list).find('OAData').each(function() {
          var xml_OAval         = $(this).attr('OAval');
          var xml_OAid          = $(this).find('OAid').text();
          var xml_BAC_Level_1       = $(this).find('BAC_Level_1').text();
          var xml_Basel_Level_1         = $(this).find('Basel_Level_1').text();
          var xml_Basel_Level_2     = $(this).find('Basel_Level_2').text();
          var xml_Risk_Category_Level_3 = $(this).find('Risk_Category_Level_3').text();

              // Add matched items to an array
              xmlArr += '<tr filterCriteria="';
              xmlArr += xml_OAval;
              xmlArr += '"><td>';
              xmlArr += xml_OAid;
              xmlArr += '</td><td>';
              xmlArr += xml_BAC_Level_1;
              xmlArr += '</td><td>';
              xmlArr += xml_Basel_Level_1;
              xmlArr += '</td><td>';
              xmlArr += xml_Basel_Level_2;
              xmlArr += '</td></tr>';


            }); // end each loop

              //Append array to table (this way is much faster than doing this individually for each item)
              $(xmlArr).appendTo(wrapper +' table tbody');
    } // end post AJAX call operaitons
    }); // end AJAX
} // end function


//Function Call
var wrapper = '#xml_wrapper'; // Id of wrapper
xml_parser(wrapper);
    }
    }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="xml_wrapper">
    <h1 id="title">My Title</h1>
    <h3 id="xml_dec_nav">Select a Category:</h3>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <form name "frmCat" action="index2.html" method="get">
            <select id="mySelect" onchange="onchange1(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                <option>Select a Category</option>
            </select>
        </form>
                    <input class="epcf" type="button" onclick="toggleDiv('epcf-wrap')" value="Options"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="buildrow('OA1')" value="Create" />
        <br/>
        </div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="header headerSortUp">OAid</th>
                    <th class="header">BAC Level 1</th>
                    <th class="header">Basel Level 1</th>
                    <th class="header">Basel Level 2</th>
                    <th class="header">Risk Category Level 3</th>           </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="epcf-wrap">
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem clearly but maybe problem can be solved using

```
$(this).find('OAval').text();
```

instead of

```
$(this).attr('OAval');
```

Comment: something like that but on the initial find - I've updated the code to clarify